Faces of model in Unreal Engine the appear transparent but in Blender the face orientation is correct
This model was imported from Blender to Unreal Engine 5. In Blender the face normals are in right direction and face orientation is also correct but when imported to unreal engine the faces are transparent as shown below.


I'm not sure if this a question about using Blender... as you show in your screenshots, everything is alright in Blender. And this site is not about Unreal Engine and I do not have it here to test myself, but could it be that there is something wrong with the material / mesh in UE? As far as I know, UE uses single-sided materials by default, I do not know if it is possible to assign them to only backfaces instead of the front. Or if there is some switch to invert the face normals in the material or the mesh...

It's because you don't have scale applied in Blender. Objects that have negative scale will get their faces flipped on export because exporting fundamentally has to apply transforms. Press Ctrl+A > Scale and I bet it will flip and look just like the Unreal mesh.

Thank you for the information. The mesh is visible now
